# wp_reset_postdata() and wp_reset_query() inside shortcode are not working to reset original page query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, shortcode, wp-reset-postdata, wp-reset-query

I'm implementing a form for a frontend post with a shortcode. The form is processed in the same function, reloading the page:

```
function adicionar_ninhada(){
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
if (isset($_POST['adicionar_cachorro'])){
    wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce'],  'brg_add_dog'.$user_id );
    $args = array(
      'post_title'    => $_POST['raca'] . " nascidos em " . $_POST['nascimento'] ,
      'post_content'  => '',
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => $user_id,
      'post_type'   => 'ninhada',
    );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $args );
    if(isset($_FILES['foto_upload'])){
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
        $attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'foto_upload', $post_id );
        if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
            echo "erro na imagem";
        } else {
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attachment_id);
        }
    }
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'raca', $_POST['raca']);
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'machos', $_POST['machos']);
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'femeas', $_POST['femeas']);
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'data', $_POST['nascimento']);
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'pai', $_POST['pai']);
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'mae', $_POST['mae']);
    echo "Adicionado com sucesso!";
}else{
    echo "<form enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" method=\"post\">
    Raça: "; 
    wp_dropdown_categories(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'raca', 
            'hide_empty' => 1,
            'show_option_none'   => 'SRD',
            'option_none_value'  => 'Outro',
            'name' => 'raca',
        )
    );
echo "<br />
    Machos: <input type=\"number\" name=\"machos\" /><br />
    Fêmeas: <input type=\"number\" name=\"femeas\" /><br />
    Data de nascimento: <input type=\"text\" name=\"nascimento\" class=\"brgdatepicker\"/><br />
    <label for=\"pai\">Pai: </label><select name=\"pai\">";
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'pai', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_status' => 'published', 'post_parent' => null); 
    $pais = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ($pais as $pai){
            echo '<option value="'.$pai->ID.'">' . get_the_title($pai->ID) . '</option>';
        }
        echo'</select><br />';
    echo "<label for=\"mae\">Mãe: </label><select name=\"mae\">";
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'mae', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_status' => 'published', 'post_parent' => null); 
    $maes = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ($maes as $mae){
            echo '<option value="'.$mae->ID.'">' . get_the_title($mae->ID) . '</option>';
        }
        echo'</select><br />';
    echo "
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"adicionar_cachorro\" value=\"1\">
    Foto: <input type=\"file\" name=\"foto_upload\" id=\"foto_upload\"  multiple=\"false\" /><br />
    <button type=\"submit\" name=\"enviar\">Salvar</button>
    ";
    wp_nonce_field( 'brg_add_dog'.$user_id );
    echo "</form>";
wp_reset_query();
}
}
add_shortcode('adicionar_ninhada', 'adicionar_ninhada');
```

I've tried already `wp_reset_postdata()` after each get_posts() foreach loop , `wp_reset_postdata()` in the end of the function and both scenarios with `wp_reset_query()` too. But the original page query is always broken after form submission and it says "Nothing found". If I comment out the `get_posts()` everything works fine.

Comment: Shortcodes must `return` content, not `echo`. `wp_reset_postdata` restores the global `$post`, `wp_reset_query` restores the global `$wp_query`. `get_posts` alters neither of those vars on its own, your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, you're right about shortcodes. I've changed the code to return an output and it's still with the same error... and why does it work when I comment out get_posts line?

Comment: When you get the "not found" result, are you sure the main query is intact before the Shortcode renders? `var_dump($wp_query)` on those requests and look at what it contains.

Comment: @Milo the `var_dump($wp_query)` gave me a clue of what's happening, and that looks really weird now. The $_POST array from the form is loaded as $wp_query->query_vars when the form is submitted. The same thing happens with the `$args` array from `get_posts()`. Since one of the `$args` key is post_type WordPress try to load the page_id where the form is but with the post_type that was used in `get_posts()`, instead of 'page' post_type. That's why it outputs "Not found". When I comment out `get_posts()` it works, because there's no post_type in the query _vars. Any idea why is that happening?

Comment: You can't have form elements that use the same names as WordPress query vars, your form element names should be changed so they are unique. There is also [a list here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms) of built in query vars that must be avoided.

Comment: The thing is that's not form elements... that's `get_posts()` that is "posting" it. Take a look at the code above, there's no "post_types" field in the form...

Comment: your post types are `mae` and `pai`, you have fields with the same names. if you've not directly modified the query var parameter of your post types, then `mae` and `pai` are query vars.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it... if I create a custom query with the name of the post_type as a key of query_vars, it won't affect the query result. And that's what happen when I comment `get_posts()`, `mae` and `pai` are keys in `query_vars` and the page is loaded. The problem is that when I uncomment `get_posts()` it place inside `query_vars` a `post_type` key with value `mae` and that breaks the page load. I'm trying to understand why it's POSTing `post_type` when it was never declared in the form. (it's just curiosity and debugging to learn. I've changed the form submission to ajax already)

Comment: I'm not following your description of what happens exactly. When your form is submitted with a form element named `mae`, WordPress parses that value as part of the main query because `mae` is a registered query var. The query's post type is set to `mae` as part of this parsing process even though you've not explicitly set `post_type` anywhere in the form.

Comment: @Milo yes, but that doesn't break the page... what breaks the page is that when I use `get_posts` it sends with the form an argument `post_type` from the `get_posts` call. But there's no element post_type in the form...

Comment: I don't think you're understanding me. You are not submitting anything named `post_type` with your form, it is getting added by WordPress because you are sending a form element named `mae`, *which is a post type*. WordPress thinks you are trying to query for a post of type `mae` with slug that matches whatever is submitted with your form. That's why you can't use any form element names that conflict with query vars.

Comment: Sorry Milo. I forgot to get back here to say that you were absolutelly right. Thanks for the help. Could you please post an answer so I can choose it?